# Why won't my code divide the remaining cents by dimes, nickels, and pennies after it divided by quarters?

Tags: java

```
    String choice = "y";
    while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        if (cents <= 99 && cents > 0){
        quarters = cents / quarters;
        System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);

        dimes = cents / dimes;
        System.out.println("Dimes: " + dimes);

        nickels = cents / nickels;
        System.out.println("Nickels: " + nickels);

        pennies = cents / pennies;
        System.out.println("Pennies: " + pennies);
```

Do i need to implement a modulus operator after each step?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: suppose you are confused with int division . this post might be helpful.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: thank you i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah you have a can't see the wood for the trees problem.

Old school trick this called a dry run

```
Cents Quarters Dimes Nickels Pennies Remaining Cents
41    1                              16
16             1                     6
6                       1            1
1                               1    0
```

You are starting from 41 each calculation.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I was able to successfully get the code to work. Thank you